# How to get access points signal data form client-side application

Tags: javascript, c#, progressive-web-apps, blazor

**Is there a way to get access point signal data from client-side code like Javascript or .Net blazor.**

For an application I'm creating I need to get the users position however I only need to know the position in correlation to the access points of a specific network. There is no need for any GPS location whatsoever. When I have the data I like to use any of the wifi positioning systems like signal strength-, fingerprinting-, angle of arrival- or time of flight based.

If it isn't possible to do this from a client I would like to know if anybody maybe knows a plan B for me.

For wifi positioning system reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system

Comment: Browser geolocation ? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: @augafrommars html 5 geolocation is gps based and I don't need to know where on earth (or mars) the user is. I only need the users distance from multiple access points in a specific network.

Comment: Is the client IP enough ?

Comment: @augafrommars unfortunately no, IP based geolocation isn't accurate enough.

Comment: I don't think the browser has enough access to get client information, but perhaps you could create a server service that provides AP information based on client IP?

Comment: @NetMage Do you know a source where a 'server service that provides AP information based on client IP' is explaint or would you explain it?